# chrome.storage.sync.remove array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am making a small Chrome extension. I would like to use `chrome.storage` but I can't get it to delete multiple items (array) from storage. Single item removal works.

```
function clearNotes(symbol)
{
    var toRemove = "{";

    chrome.storage.sync.get(function(Items) {
        $.each(Items, function(index, value) {
            toRemove += "'" + index + "',";         
        });
        if (toRemove.charAt(toRemove.length - 1) == ",") {
            toRemove = toRemove.slice(0,- 1);
        }
        toRemove = "}";
        alert(toRemove);
    });

    chrome.storage.sync.remove(toRemove, function(Items) {
        alert("removed");
        chrome.storage.sync.get( function(Items) {
            $.each(Items, function(index, value) {
                alert(index);           
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Nothing seems to break but the last loop that alerts out what is in the storage still shows all the values I am trying to delete.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you pass in a string to `sync.remove`, Chrome will attempt to remove the *one single item* whose key matches the input string. If you need to remove multiple items, use an array of key values.

Also, you should move your `remove` call to inside your `get` callback.

```
function clearNotes(symbol)
{
// CHANGE: array, not a string
var toRemove = [];

chrome.storage.sync.get( function(Items) {
    $.each(Items, function(index, value)
    {
        // CHANGE: add key to array
        toRemove.push(index);         
    });

    alert(toRemove);

    // CHANGE: now inside callback
    chrome.storage.sync.remove(toRemove, function(Items) {
        alert("removed");

        chrome.storage.sync.get( function(Items) {
            $.each(Items, function(index, value)
            {
                alert(index);           
            });
        });
    }); 
});

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly Slimmer and updated solution

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get(null, (data) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(data).filter((x) => x.startsWith('<start-of-key>')); // Can replace `startsWith` with regex or any other string comparison
    chrome.storage.sync.remove(keys);
});
```