# chrome.storage remove specific item from an array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

This is the JSON stored in my chrome local storage

```
{"users":[
    {"password":"123","userName":"alex"},
    {"password":"234","userName":"dena"},
    {"password":"343","userName":"jovit"}
]}
```

Is it possible to remove a specific item in "users" ?
I tried to this code but no luck

```
chrome.storage.local.remove('users[0]', function(){
    alert('Item deleted!');
});
```

Comment: is this ``StorageArea.remove(string or array of string keys, function callback)`` the same method as yours?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927378/chrome-storage-sync-remove-array-doesnt-work

Comment: @doniyor Im not sure but I think thats it. here is the documentation im using [link]https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Comment: @AlexCoroza yeah then it is the same

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is not a duplicate, @RobW.

Comment: @Lakshay I saw that solution earlier but it can only remove the whole object. In my case, it will delete the "users" object

Comment: @doniyor following the documentation, I can only remove the whole "users". What I want is to remove some items in "users"

Comment: @RobW Maybe I'm not fully awake yet, but I don't see how the duplicate deals with deleting sub-items (like this question wants, and you correctly said that it's impossible). It deals with deleting multiple top-level items at once.

Comment: @Xan It's me who was not awake. I have re-opened the question and converted my comment to an answer. (I'll delete this comment also after you've read it, it is not relevant to future visitors)

Comment: @AlexCoroza i see. your question isnot duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no magic syntax to delete only one element from an array that is stored in `chrome.storage`. In order to delete an item from the array, you has to retrieve the stored array, throw away the unwanted items (or equivalently, keep only the items that you want to keep), then save the array again:

```
chrome.storage.local.get({users: []}, function(items) {
    // Remove one item at index 0
    items.users.splice(0, 1);
    chrome.storage.set(items, function() {
        alert('Item deleted!');
    });
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice.

Note that if you want to delete one or more items whose value satisfies a certain condition, you have to walk the array *in reverse order*. Otherwise you may end up removing the wrong items since the indices of the later elements are off by one after removing the first item, off by two when you've removed two items, etc.

Comment: ah I see. I thought there is a built in function for that. ok i'll use this solution

Comment: @AlexCoroza The reason behind not having such a function is that despite automagically accepting and returning JSON-compatible values, `chrome.storage` serializes them, and therefore it's database is made of strings that have no "sub-items".

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can try this

```
chrome.storage.sync.remove("token");
```

[see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/remove)